# Implementing random color button in my code

Tags: python, processing

I need to make a button that when I press it it generates a random color that #I can use to draw with. I have looked up some other random color generators but I dont know how to implement it. Here is my code so far.

```
from processing import *


tool = "paintbrush"
tool = "shapechanger"
red_color = 0
green_color = 0
blue_color = 0

def setup():
  size(400,400)
  draw_red_button()


def draw_red_button():
  set_red()
  fill(red_color, green_color, blue_color)
  rect(0, 380, 20, 20)

def red_button_pressed():
    if mouse.pressed and (mouse.x>0 and 
                        mouse.x<20 and 
                        mouse.y>380 and 
                        mouse.y<400):
        return True
    else:
        return False  

def draw():
    if red_button_pressed():
      set_red()
    else:
      fill(red_color, green_color, blue_color)
      paint()
      stroke(red_color, green_color, blue_color)

def paint():
  if mouse.pressed:
     ellipse(mouse.x, mouse.y, 20,20)



def set_red():
  global red_color
  global green_color
  global blue_color
  red_color = 255
  green_color = 0
  blue_color = 0






run()
```

Comment: Please post the MINIMAL necessary example if you want to get help. Does your problem change if you have only one color button instead of a dozen? If not, why do you make us read a dozen of almost identical function definitions?

Comment: I have just made it smaller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading the current Processing environment, below is the solution I came up with.  (Your code hints at a different version of this software so you may need to adjust accordingly.)

```
from processing import *

red_color, green_color, blue_color = 0, 0, 0

# Programmer defined functions

def draw_random_button():
    fill(255, 255, 255)
    rect(0, 380, 20, 20)

def overButton():
    return 0 < mouseX < 20 and 380 < mouseY < 400

def paint():
    if mousePressed:
        ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20)

def set_random_color():
    global red_color
    global green_color
    global blue_color

    red_color = random(256)
    green_color = random(256)
    blue_color = random(256)

    fill(red_color, green_color, blue_color)

# System defined functions

def setup():
    size(400, 400)
    draw_random_button()
    set_random_color()

def mousePressed():
    if overButton():
        set_random_color()

def draw():
    if not overButton():
        paint()
        stroke(red_color, green_color, blue_color)
```

One confusing thing is that `mousePressed` is a variable you can test *and* a function you can define.

[image]